# Criar uma series booleana cujo nome é a variável de um for no python

Tags: python, pandas

Quero fazer um `for` considerando uma lista de nomes.

A segunda linha funciona normalmente, criando novas colunas com o nome da variável na lista. O Problema está na segunda.

Como integro o nome da variável `t` no nome da series na segunda linha?

```
teores_completos = ['fegl','sigl','pgl','algl','mngl','pfgl','cagl','mggl','tigl','fogl','f3gl']

for t in teores_completos:
    dataframe[ t + '_iso_bool'] = 0
    fegl_iso_bool = dataframe[t] > 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recomendo utilizar um dicionário, facilita a inserção e a busca por nome/string.

```
teores_completos = ['fegl','sigl','pgl','algl','mngl','pfgl','cagl','mggl','tigl','fogl','f3gl']
 
is_bool = {}
for t in teores_completos:
    dataframe[ t + '_iso_bool'] = 0
    is_bool[t] = dataframe[t] > 0
```

> Só garanta que `dataframe[t] > 0` retorna apenas True, False (ou 0,1). Porque se retornar mais coisas, vai salvar junto no dicionario, e não terá um dicionario com apenas boleanos. Nos meus testes, tive que usar `(dataframe[t] > 0)[0]` mas vai depender como é a estrutura do seu `dataframe`.